# Randomized colors on texture tiles?

Tags: texturing, materials, shader-nodes

I am trying to make a skyscraper, and I want the windows to **randomly be on or off**.  In the image shown below, on the middle skyscraper, the **windows are a repeating 2x2 texture**, where three of the pixels are transparent and one is opaque.  This texture is mixed with the gradient texture below (a 4x4 Cubic texture), with the windows' opacity as the Fac.

[image]

I would like to **randomize the color of each tile** of the window texture, to make most windows yellow, and some black.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hi :). Are your windows actual geometry, or just colored squares on a texture?

Comment: The windows are colored squares on a texture.  They're a 2x2 texture where 3 pixels are transparent and one is white.

Comment: Can you please, show us how your image texture and UV map looks like? I made a node setup that can help you but I need to see how the texture looks like and how it is mapped on your building. Or if you could share the blend file, it would be better.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://imgur.com/yXb1w6s https://imgur.com/kBMJLiN?

Answer (score 2):

with this nodes setup:

[image]

[image]

you get this:

[image]

Comment: Oh that's very nice. Love the versatility :)

Comment: Thank you very much!