# How to Make Simple Windows Repeat Around Rectangle Building Randomly Per Side?

Tags: modeling, objects, add-on, edit-mode

Is it possible to make this type of building design without having to manually add and paste each window square on the building?

[image]

I want to create multiple types of this building and would be tedious to manually add each square then copy to the next building etc.

Is there an add on or method for making this repeating window without manually adding each one?

Note the only method I'm aware of is adding a ton of loop cuts like this

Is this the correct method for this type of design?

[image]

Update windows look like this using brick texture

[image]

Comment: Hi :). There was an almost identical question like a week ago. Try searching this site ;)

Comment: do you have a link to that question? because I only found ones about a detailed city or extruding windows, which isn't the same thing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Randomized colors on texture tiles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258307/randomized-colors-on-texture-tiles)

Comment: only the random part, but I also want to make sure the correct method for actually making the windows as well because I'm not sure if adding a ton of loop cuts is correct or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the **Brick** texture, that I've assigned to specific faces:

[image]

Top and bottom faces have solid color, middle ones has a **Brick** texture.

This is a node setup for sharing one material between window section and solid section:

[image]

Walls material is in the node group.

How to: https://youtu.be/jGWatXzxHb4

You can use **correct face attributes** for quick resizing:

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you show the wireframe for making the actual windows? or is it just like I showed above with a ton of loop cuts? or that is just a literally texture that comes with blender that looks like windows?

Comment: Updated in the answer body. Brick texture looks like you need, if you adjust some values.

Comment: my top windows are cut off? How did you get yours to perfectly align with each other? I added my image in my question and I tried updating the numbers but they didn't match perfectly

Comment: Set offset to 0, and check other settings

Comment: okay I think I got that, but the only issue is unless I use black for the building, the brick texture section won't match my actual building color because that 3rd color option called mortar isn't the exact color of the principal bsdf. Did you manage to match the mortar color with the building using a different color besides black? even using the exact hex code it still is slightly darker

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: one issue I just realized why my windows aren't aligned is because when I increase the brick width, it moves along the z axis and not x??? why is that? basically width option makes my windows taller instead of wider

Comment: I had to cube project them from the uv tab to make them work along the correct axis